# Cannot find module sails-swagger

Tags: git, npm, sails.js

I have installed a package using `npm install https://github.com/langateam/sails-swagger.git --save`. It installed successfully in the node_module folder of my current directory. But when I run the application then it shows error `Can not find module sails-swagger`.
I am using the sails js framework for node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it and faced the same problem. Luckily I was able to fix it.

1. Remove node_modules `rm -rf node_modules`
2. Add `"sails-swagger": "0.5.1"` to `package.json`
3. run `npm install`
4. Add `config/swagger.js` as described here https://github.com/langateam/sails-swagger#configuration
5. `sails lift` and visit localhost:1337/swagger/doc